# XML parse in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Trying to use an xml in javascript.  The emailtest.xml needs to be taken from the same folder as emailtest.js and emailtest.html.  I am not sure how to use the parser.  Is there a right way to address a xml in js?

//emailtest.js

```
function window_open(){
    parser= new DOMparser();
    email = parser.parseFromString("emailtest.xml", "text/xml);
    textbox1.text=email(1,1)
    
}
```

//emailtest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<table>
    <0>
        <fname>John</fname>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
        <email>doejohn@gmail.com</email>
    </0>
    <1>
        <fname>Jane</fname>
        <lname>Doe</lname>
        <email>doejane@yahoo.com</email>
    </1>
</table>
```

Comment: `.parseFromString()` expects the first argument to be the XML content itself, not the name of a file with XML in it.

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).

Comment: What content  goes in .parseFromString() if not the name of the file?

Comment: const xmlString = "<warning>Beware of the missing closing tag";// HOW DO YOU add the file emailtest.xml to xmlString/